# Configuración del botón "Upload Files" en PHP, error en el código

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

¡Hola! Tengo un formulario de contacto donde pueden escribir su nombre, email, teléfono y un mensaje. Estos datos me llegan sin ningún problema, el problema es el botón "AÑADIR IMÁGENES", para empezar, quiero que sólamente puedan enviar archivos jpg y png, además que les salga que sus archivos se están cargando o que ya se cargaron, porque le doy click, selecciono el archivo y no sé cuándo ya se cargó, etc. Además al correo no me llegan los archivos, sólamente los otros campos. En pocas palabras, el botón de "añadir imágenes" es inútil.

Código [HTML]:

```
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Contáctanos</h2>
        <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Llámenos al 442.432.29.55</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Su Nombre*" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte su nombre">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Su Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte su email.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Su teléfono *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte un teléfono válido.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Características de su vehículo *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Porfavor inserte su mensaje."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
               <div style="position: relative; margin: 25px; padding: 10px; width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: #236eaa; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #262f35; ">
                <p style="text-align: center; color: white; font-family: 'Montserrat', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji'; font-weight: bold;">AÑADIR IMÁGENES</p>
                <input name="files[]" id="imagenes" type="file" placeholder="imágenes" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte archivos JPG o PNG." multiple style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;" class="btn">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
              <div id="success"></div>
              <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

En esta parte verán mi código php, al parecer me falta añadir una variable, pero si lo hago como las demás me marca error, lo dejé así porque si le cambio algo deja de funcionar completamente, espero alguien pueda apoyarme con el código correcto, muchas gracias!

Código [PHP]:

```
    <?php
// Campos vacíos
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Email
$to = 'autoparteselromeral@hotmail.com';
$email_subject = "Contacto de compra de autos:  $name";
$email_body = "Ha recibido un mensaje.\n\n"."Estos son los detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nTel: $phone\n\nMensaje:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noresponder@chocadosmexico.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Comment: Hola @Luis Olivárez. Tal vez esta respuesta te pueda servir: [insert-image-in-mail-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390138/insert-image-in-mail-body). Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

si tu servidor no tiene habilitado la opcion de enviar email no podras hacerlo ya que requiere un servidor con un FQDN valido:
lo mejor para enviar correos desde php siempre a sido phpmailer..

aca te dejo un ejemplo de uso para enviar con una cuenta de gmail:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

para insertar imagenes debes agregar un campo multiple al final y un name="files[]" que sera un tipo array list:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="files[]" id="imagenes" type="file" placeholder="imagenes" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor inserte un teléfono válido." multiple>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
```

en php debes hacer un foreach or for para recorrer el arreglo:
ejemplo directo de php manual:
http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Gracias amigo, el servidor está configurado correctamente :D es un vps y ya tengo otros dominios en ese host que dejan mandar imágenes, solamente quiero un "button" que permita al usuario insertar unas 5 imágenes con sus datos y me lleguen a mi correo :) ¡Saludos! Espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: ya lo edite :D para lo que necesitavas!

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya puse el botón pero en php no conseguí hacer el código :(